# Do i need to use the <noscript> in this code?

Tags: html

The code below is used in the index.html and seems to work ok.

When i try to use the same code () in an html file in a subfolder it does not display any of the css.

Is the  tag neccessary on the main index.html file?

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title> </title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.dropotron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slidertron.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel-layers.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    **<noscript>**
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
    **</noscript>**
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie/v8.css" /><![endif]-->
</head>
```

Comment: what do you think 'noscript' does?

Comment: the `noscript` is a body tag and cant be placed in the `head` ,but to answer ur question u should use `modernizer` which u simply append any thing u want to work only when JS is disabled by `no-js` ,read more http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Why would you use `noscript` there? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I purchased a template that has this code in the head of index.html. i understand from some research that it can now be placed in the head on html5 but I asked my question because my knowledge of html is rather limited and i cannot (personally) see why it is there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

To have it display the css when you're in a subfolder, add ../ infront of the relative path to the css document. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/skel.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style-desktop.css" />
```

Comment: This is what you're looking for

Comment: Hi and thanks - i did the above but it did not work with the noscript tag in place - works fine without noscript tag.

Comment: Yes, you're not supposed to use the noscript tag in the head section. Juat ditch the noscript from head.